# AJAX Callback not firing during cross domain request

Tags: jquery

I have the following script:

```
var queryString = $("#recurringForm").serialize();

                        var action = "https://www.beanstream.com/scripts/recurring_billing.asp?" + queryString;

                        $.ajax({url : action,
                            type: 'GET', 
                            success : function () {
                                alert("this should be called");
                                submitPayment();
                            }
                        });
```

Everything here works except for the callback. Is this because I'm posting to a domain different from my own? If so, how do I get around this.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? From 1.5 it has crossDomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is because it's a different domain. Your browser will not allow it. Instead, you should send an AJAX request to a route on your server, and execute the GET from your server.

Comment: would you be able to provide an example of that in c#?

Comment: No, I'm sure you could look it up though. Look for docs on sending HTTP requests with C#.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain calls are blocked by browsers. The only exception to this is JSONP calls. Check out the jQuery docs and consider using .getJSON instead of ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/